# What are the biggest comebacks in NFL postseason history?

Tags: american-football, trivia, history, nfl, postseason

The New England Patriots overcame a 25 point deficit to beat the Atlanta Falcons in Super Bowl 51. What are the top 5 comebacks in the NFL playoffs history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing unashamedly from [ESPN](https://www.espn.com/blog/statsinfo/post/_/id/129452/what-are-the-greatest-comebacks-in-nfl-postseason-history) for the top four:

1. 32 points: [Bills vs Oilers, 1993](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199301030buf.htm): Buffalo trailed 35-3, but went on to win 41-38.
2. 28 points: [Colts vs Chiefs, 2014](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201401040clt.htm): Colts trailed 38-10, but went on to win 45-44.
3. 25 points: Patriots vs Falcons, 2017: Patriots trailed 28-3, but went on to win 34-28.
4. 24 points: [49ers vs Giants, 2003](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200301050sfo.htm): 49ers trailed 38-14, but went on to win 39-38.

Answer (score 2):

5. 20 points (1957): [Lions at 49ers](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/195712220sfo.htm), Lions trailed 27-7 in the divisional round but went on to win 31-27.